# output file naming

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, naming-conventions

Alright, So I am using a batch process of raster calculator and in the calculator I am using 2 different raster files (meridional and zonal). This calculator will be running for 24 files of each the meridional and zonal. So one run will calculate an output file for, say, Mericional_0000 and Zonal_0000; then the next run will use Meridional_0100 and Zonal_0100, all the way till 2300. Is there a way that when the calculator runs, the output for Meridional_0000 and Zonal_0000 will go to one file while the Zonal_0100 and Meridional_0100 will go to another file. [each of the 24 files will have its own file when calculated]. I tried the %Name%, but that gives me an output for each individual file, and I don't want that. Any help would be great!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the outputs in the same folder?

Comment: I want them in the same folder, but I want each run of the model builder (which is doing batch run, 24 times) to be saved in its own output file.

Comment: Are you using the actual "Batch" option or are you running this in ModelBuilder?

Comment: in model builder. I am new to the batch option, so I don't know where to find it within ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: ModelBuilder is the way to go if you do not use Python.  However, here is a link to the batch mode: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000

Answer (score 1):

How are your files named in the first instance?  I am presuming that you are working in a file workspace as opposed to geodatabase workspace.

If you are using model builder perhaps use two instances of calculator,  one to calculate the zonal one to calculate the meridional.  In the one instance of calculator you can set the output name to be Meridional_%Name% and the other to be Zonal_%Name%.  You may wish to send them to different output locations too.

> Is there a way that when the calculator runs, the output for Meridional_0000 and Zonal_0000 will go to one file while the Zonal_0100 and Meridional_0100 will go to another file.

Do you mean another folder instead?  If so, you can use model builder to create a new folder on each iteration using the original file name to name it.

If I've understood you correctly we should be able to crack this no problem but more information is needed to give a full answer.